# Is an image of a stripe considered copyrighted?

Tags: copyright, background-image, copy

I have an image that I found on another site. It's just a one pixle wide stripe, and I'm wondering if it's protected by copyright.

[image: One pixel wide stripe]

Comment: Post a link to it, and we can decide for you what's acceptable. If it's a gradient or something, should be fine to use. Vectors may or may not be copyrighted, but most certainly any photographs are.

Comment: @ionFish updated question

Comment: Yeah, I see no possible way someone can copyright a stripe. You should be able to use it no questions asked. You could even change the color by two shades if you're paranoid.

Comment: Please close the question by selecting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That image can't be copyrighted. In order for something to be copyrighted, it has to be an "original work", or be something like a book or an image that required creativity, imagination, etc. to create. A stripe can be created by anyone, without even thinking about it, **so it does not fall under copyright restrictions**.

Semi related: if you are going to try to use an actual *picture* as a background, one that is protected by copyright (see above), you should make sure that your allowed to do so.

Comment: but in my case there isn't any problem, correct?

Comment: @fxuser you will have absolutely no problem with using that image.